# Incorrect Output results displaying for some values in a python programme

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a python program in Visio code and I found a strange Behavior

code:

```
a=input("Enter Jim age ") 

b=input("Enter Michal age ") 

c=input("Enter sunny age ") 

d=input("Enter Anders age ") 

if(a>b):     
    print("Jim is elder") 

if(b>c):     
    print("Michal is elder")  

if(c>d):     
    print("sunny is elder") 
else:     
    print("nothing is true")
```

Now when I input values `13,11,9,8` it will display only `"Jim is elder sunny is elder"` which is incorrect. But if I put the input values `20,18,16,14` ,it will display all the results correctly.
The same incorrect results also showing when I input `11,9,8,7` in which case output is `" Michal is elder sunny is elder"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need convert the input string to `int` before comparing them like so:

```
a= int(input("Enter Jim age ")) 

b= int(input("Enter Michal age ")) 

c= int(input("Enter sunny age "))

d= int(input("Enter Anders age "))

if(a>b):     
    print("Jim is elder") 

if(b>c):     
    print("Michal is elder")  

if(c>d):     
    print("sunny is elder") 
else:     
    print("nothing is true")
```

Comment: Thanks. But still i didnt get why the earlier condition had worked for few values while not for others

Comment: Python compares strings character by character, in your first test case, i.e `13 11 9 8`. The first test case passes as `"13"` > `"11"` (1 and 1 are equal so next python compares 3 and 1). However, when `11` and `9` are compared, 1 and 9 are being compared, so "9" is evaluated to be greater than "11" . I may have butchered the explanation a bit, but look up a few articles and you'll get a clearer idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a=int(input("Enter Jim age "))

b=int(input("Enter Michal age "))

c=int(input("Enter sunny age "))

d=int(input("Enter Anders age "))

if(a>b):
  print("Jim is elder")

if(b>c):
  print("Michal is elder")

if(c>d):
  print("sunny is elder") 

else:
  print("nothing is true")
```

Comment: I think the OP wants all correct conditions to be printed, using `elif` will ignore the rest of the conditions once one is satisfied